# Convergent Subsequence and metric

Tags: real-analysis

Consider a sequence $y_n$ in a metric space. If $d(y_n, y_m) \geq \epsilon$ for all $n$ and $m$, why does this imply that $y_n$ has no convergent subsequence?

My understanding is that this implies that the sequence is not Cauchy, which further implies that $y_n$ is not convergent, which implies it has no convergent subsequences. Does this make sense?

Comment: "There exists $\;\epsilon > 0\;$ such that..." ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean that $d(y_n,y_m)\ge\epsilon$ for all $n$ and $m$ with $n\ne m$, since of course $d(y_n,y_n)=0$.

Your understanding is partly correct. This certainly does imply that the sequence is not Cauchy and therefore is not convergent, but that fact does not imply that it has no convergent subsequence. The sequence $\langle 1,-1,1,-1,\ldots\rangle$ is not Cauchy and hence not convergent, but it has convergent subsequences $\langle 1,1,1,\ldots\rangle$ and $\langle -1,-1,-1,\ldots\rangle$.

The original hypothesis, however, *is* strong enough to imply that $\langle y_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ has no convergent subsequence. Just observe that any subsequence also has that property and therefore, by the argument that you gave, is not convergent.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $y_n$ has a convergent subsequence $y_{a_i}$ such that $\displaystyle \lim_{i \rightarrow \infty} y_{a_i} \rightarrow L$. Then there exist $j,k$ such that $d(y_{a_j}, L) < \frac{\epsilon}2$ and $d(y_{a_k}, L ) < \frac{\epsilon}2$.

Then by the triangle inequality, $$\epsilon = \frac{\epsilon}2 + \frac{\epsilon}2 > d(y_{a_j}, L) + d(y_{a_k}, L) \ge d(y_{a_j}, y_{a_k}),$$

contradiction.